# Height of custom keyboard in iOS and Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard

How to get the height of the view given by iOS to a custom keyboard?

I am currently setting the keyboard interface manually for an iPhone 8 Plus:

```
var keyboardHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height > UIScreen.main.bounds.width ? 226 : 162
}
```

How get the height of the keyboard for all size classes programmatically?

Comment: Are you writing code in the custom keyboard or in a view controller?  If you are writing code in the keyboard then your code specifies the keyboard height. If you are writing in a view controller then you should use the keyboard notifications as Andrea said.

Comment: @Paulw11 the code is written in the custom keyboard controller. The height ios gives to custom keyboard varies from one device to another.

Comment: You either set the height of your keyboard using constraints or you can obtain the default height by looking at the frame of your keyboard parent view.

Comment: Here, I created  something you might need https://federicabenacquista.medium.com/list-of-the-official-ios-keyboards-heights-and-how-to-calculate-them-c2b844ef54b9?sk=e7490c5f0236be791a1b6f4eda6e1e2f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let desiredHeight: CGFloat =  500
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: desiredHeight)
    view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)), for: .allTouchEvents)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way is the usual one: [listen to keyboard notifications and respond to them](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html).
The `endFrame` key of the `userInfo` dictionary sent along with the notification contains the correct size of the keyboard. I takes into account also eventual `accessoryInputView`.

Comment: I need the height that iOS will give to this custom keyboard in any app, on any device. I don't have access to text fields and text views to be notified when the keyboard will be shown or hidden.